# Making multiple S3 write operation in nodejs using Promise.all doesn't work

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I have a use case where I have to upload multiple json data to s3. I am having below code in my service file.

```
if (s3Payload.length > 0) {
       await Promise.all(_.map(s3Payload,async (item)=>{
            await this.s3Repository.uploadData(
            item,
            'some-random-key'
            )
}));
```

And below is the code for uploadData function

```
uploadData = async (data, fileName) => {
    const params = {
      Bucket: this.bucketName,
      Key: fileName,
      Body: Buffer.from(
        JSON.stringify(data)
      ),
      ServerSideEncryption: 'aws:kms',
      BucketKeyEnabled: true,
      SSEKMSKeyId: this.kmsKey,
      ContentType: 'application/json'
    };
    try {
      console.log('calling s3')
      const result = await this.s3.upload(params).promise();
      console.log(result.Location)
      return { statusCode: 200, location: result.Location };
    } catch (err) {
      return { statusCode: 500, errorMessage: err };
    }   };
```

When I run this , only `'calling s3'` gets printed and the not the actual location (second console log) and the program exits normally. So I am guessing that the upload call is not completing before the program exits.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code is working but there's an error on this line:

`const result = await this.s3.upload(params).promise();`

That would mean the second console.log never gets executed.

It's worth console logging the output of the `Promise.all` afterwards to see what was successful. Maybe it's an AWS credentials issue that you are masking by catching the errors.

```
if (s3Payload.length > 0) {
       const promises = s3Payload.map((data, i) => {
         return this.s3Repository.uploadData(
            data,
            `some-random-key-${i}`,
         )
       });
       const payloads = await Promise.all(promises);
       console.log(payloads);
}));
```